# I get the unauthorized action error when doing route:list?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, console

Not much to say here, except that I'm confused? Any help? Can't find an answer to this either!

I will provide some extra context if you'd like me to; just not sure where to start.

[image: Unauthorized action]

This is my auth.php. The customer guard is custom:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users'
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
],
```

This is my CustomersController which just has the index function in it. Removing or adding the construct back makes no difference:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class CustomersController extends Controller
{
/*public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth.customers');
}*/

public function index()
{
    return view('customers');
}
}
```

Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class Customers extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
use Authenticatable;

protected $guard = 'customers';

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'customers';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password'];

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array $fillable
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'username',
    'email',
    'password',
    'remember_token'
];
}
```

and a route:

```
Route::get('/customers', 'CustomersController@index');
```

Comment: Is this problem appears from the start? I mean, from the fresh installation of Laravel?

Comment: It's a project I've worked on a while. I've started working with new controllers and new guard types. I created a `CustomerController`, model and a simple view, with a `customer` guard in auth.php. Could this have caused it?

Comment: Maybe. Could you please share your Laravel log file?

Comment: `storage/logs`? it's empty.

Comment: I've edited the post and added code.

Comment: Weird. Everything looks good. How about you run the route:list command in verbose mode `php artisan route:list -v`? It gives any detailed error?

Comment: Are you using `Zizaco/entrust` package in this project?

Comment: @wlisrausr this is what that command gives me. don't know where to begin https://pastebin.com/eRWPjaLz

Comment: @SazzadurRahman nope